# How to filter array of objects by object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Good day. Tell me how can I iterate over an array taking values for filters from an object?

```js
const hotels = [
  {
    name: "Marina Inn",
    country: "США"
    address: "Фалираки",
    stars: 4,  
  },    
  {
    name: "Mondrian Suites",
    country: "Греция",
    address: "Родос",
    stars: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "Mondrian Suites",
    country: "США",
    address: "Родос",
    stars: 5,
  }      
]
```

I want to filter objects by filters from object:

```js
const objFilter = {     
  country: "США",      
  stars: 5,      
}
```

You should get an array

```js
[
  {
    name: "Mondrian Suites",
    country: "США",
    address: "Родос",
    stars: 5,
  }      
]
```

Comment: Try this,
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Your title asks about sorting, but the content asks about filtering. Which do you need? Also, there are native JS Array functions for doing both, please check MDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the pairs of the filter object.

Then, using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), iterate over the array and return the matching elements using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const filterArrByObj = (arr = [], obj = {}) => {
  const filterEntries = Object.entries(obj);
  return arr.filter(e =>
    filterEntries.every(([key, value]) => e[key] === value)
  );
}

const 
  hotels = [{ name: "Marina Inn", country: "США", address: "Фалираки", stars: 4 }, { name: "Mondrian Suites", country: "Греция", address: "Родос", stars: 5 }, { name: "Mondrian Suites", country: "США", address: "Родос", stars: 5 }],
  objFilter = { country: "США", stars: 5 };
console.log( filterArrByObj(hotels, objFilter) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop and check if object has the values you want like -
(Note: New to JS, didn't tried but hope it works)

```
var filter = {     
      country: США,      
      stars: 5,      
    {

hotels.forEach(function(hotel){
  if(hotel.country == filter.country && hotel.stars == filter.stars) {
      console.log(hotel);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const hotels = [
          {
            name: "Marina Inn",
            country: "США",address: "Фалираки",
            stars: 4
          },
          {
            name: "Mondrian Suites",
            country: "Греция",
            address: "Родос",
            stars: 5,
            
          },
          {
            name: "Mondrian Suites",
            country: "США",
            address: "Родос",
            stars: 5,
            
          }
        ]
            
    const results = hotels.filter(hotel=>hotel.country =='США'&&hotel.stars==5);
```